# Nelder-Mead Algorithm in boost library

Tags: c++, boost, mathematical-optimization

I was wondering if the Nelder-Mead Algorithm is implemented in c++ boost library like the toms748_solve. I couldn't find it in the documentation and I ask you before implement the code my self.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? Boost is not a single library, but a collection of quite a few libraries (see [this list](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/)). Which specific library are you wondering about?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Perhaps my problem is directly related with the documentation. I'm looking for the a functionality to find the minimum value of a 1D-fucntion like the Nelder-Mead algorithm. Actually, I've been using the algorithm toms748_solve (boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/math/doc/html/toolkit.html) for Root finding without derivatives, but now I want to minimize the function.

Comment: Isn't minimizing a function equal to finding the roots of the derivative, and then discarding the maxima?

Comment: yes, it is the same. In particular, I'm looking for an algorithm like  the Nelder-Mead where I only use the function and an initial guest (not an initial interval). For example, right now I'm using the brent algorithm (boost::math::tools::brent_find_minima) but I need to introduce an interval where the function change. Thanks.

Comment: No, it is not the same as the derivative might not exist or if it exists the derivative might not be continuous, which makes it difficult to find roots in practice. Furthermore, I would like to point out that there are roots of the derivative that are neither minimum nor maximum, hence discarding the latter is not sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the amoeba (Nelder-Meade downhill simplex) algorithm is implemented by vnl library (http://public.kitware.com/vxl/doc/release/core/vnl/html/classvnl__amoeba.html#details), so I'm going to use this library instead of boost. 
I know that I've been looking for an implementation of this algorithm using the boost::math library and this answer is not related directly with my question, but perhaps it could be useful for others too.